# multiple executions of PMD maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, pmd

I try to execute PMD maven plugin multiple times with different configurations at the same time. The executions do work but they always uses the first configuration. My idea was to check java, jsp and javascript alltogether with just "mvn verify".

Can't find any similar documentation or problem out there.

My configuration is as follows:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
            <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <!-- test java -->
            <execution>
                <id>check-java</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <language>java</language>
                    <sourceEncoding>cp1252</sourceEncoding>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>/category/java/bestpractices.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>/category/java/codestyle.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>/category/java/design.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>/category/java/errorprone.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>/category/java/multithreading.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>/category/java/performance.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <!-- test jsp -->
            <!-- currently only the first configuration is working -->
            <execution>
                <id>check-jsp</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <language>jsp</language>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>/category/jsp/bestpractices.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>/category/jsp/codestyle.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>/category/jsp/design.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>/category/jsp/errorprone.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>/category/jsp/security.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.jsp</include>
                    </includes>
                    <compileSourceRoots>
                        <compileSourceRoot>${basedir}/WebContent</compileSourceRoot>
                    </compileSourceRoots>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <!-- test javascript -->
            <!-- currently only the first configuration is working -->
            <execution>
                <id>check-javascript</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <language>javascript</language>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>/category/ecmascript/bestpractices.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>/category/ecmascript/codestyle.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>/category/ecmascript/errorprone.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.js</include>
                    </includes>
                    <compileSourceRoots>
                        <compileSourceRoot>${basedir}/WebContent/javascript</compileSourceRoot>
                    </compileSourceRoots>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution: the goal needs to be pmd, only this goal has the used configuration values.